# Attempting to upload file on Linux Mint LAMP server results in error 500

Tags: php, html, lamp

I am attempting upload a file using html/php and when I send a post request with the file, I get a 500 Internal Server Error. This only happens when I have the php code `move_uploaded_files($_FILES['filetoUpload']['tmp_name'], $target_file);`
I have checked the php.ini file to confirm `file_uploads' = On` and I have confirmed that the permissions of the directory allow creating files. When I do a `print_r($_FILES)` I successfully see the array with all the file information. For some reason, when I try to save the file with the move_uploaded files function, the file doesn't upload and I get a internal error 500 come back.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs for any useful info?

Comment: try enabling the error reporting for the page execution process! that would help to get some errors

Comment: Do you happen to know where the error logs are kept?

Comment: Found them! /var/log/apache2 and it appears to be giving me good information! Thank you!